# Replace nan value in a pandas dataframe where column is string type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dat = pd.DataFrame({'aa' : [np.nan, 'A'], 'bb' : [123, np.nan]})
dat['aa'] = dat['aa'].astype('str')
dat.fillna('')
```

However above code failed to replace `nan` value in the string column.

Is there any way get a solution of above issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

delete `astype('str')` line

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
   
dat = pd.DataFrame({'aa' : [np.nan, 'A'], 'bb' : [123, np.nan]})
# delete dat['aa'] = dat['aa'].astype('str')
dat.fillna('')
```

If you have a specific reason to use `dat['aa'] = dat['aa'].astype('str')`

use following:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'aa' : [np.nan, 'A'], 'bb' : [123, np.nan]})
dat['aa'] = dat['aa'].fillna('').astype('str')
dat.fillna('')
```

or

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'aa' : [np.nan, 'A'], 'bb' : [123, np.nan]})
dat['aa'] = dat['aa'].fillna('')
dat.fillna('').replace('nan', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps?:

```
dat.replace('nan', '')
```